# Examples of when $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $X\times X$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory

I was thinking about this question the other day: When is a topological space $X$ homotopy equivalent to $X\times X$ (with the product topology)? This is essentially a cross-post of this [MSE question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4809332/when-is-x-homotopy-equivalent-to-x-times-x).

If $X$ is contractible, this works of course. Let, e.g., $X=\mathbb R$.

Another example (given in the comments of the linked post) is to take a group $G$ such that $G\cong G\times G$, and then take $X=K(G,1)$.

It seems (very?) hard to come up with necessary and sufficient conditions on $X$ to make $X\simeq X\times X$, but what are some other examples of spaces for which this is true?

Comment: Take any space $X$ and consider its product with itself some infinite number of times $X^A$. Then $X^A \times X^A$ is simply homeomorphic to $X^A$. For example, an infinite-dimensional torus (countable product of copies of $S^1$), etc.

Comment: I think we have a duplicate thread on this topic, but I'm having trouble finding it.  Perhaps someone else remembers the right keyword?

Comment: See answers here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3493139/topological-space-which-is-homeomorphic-to-its-square

Comment: A reasonable question would be about  connected CW complexes with this property.

Comment: Presumably Arshak's example is the answer.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for the link, I had neglected to search for the same question for homeomorphism. The comments of your linked post have several more links as well! I figured this would have been asked somewhere at some point.